# Balanced Partition (Finding the minimized sum between two partitions of a set of positive integers)

Tags: algorithm

I am solving using *dynamic* problem.

My `C` code is below :

```
int balanced_partition( int arr[] , int n){

    int i,j;
    int sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        sum+=arr[i];

    int p[n+1][sum+1];
    for(i=0;i<n+1;i++){
            for(j=0;j<sum+1;j++){
                    if(i==0)
                            p[0][j]= 0;
                    else if(j==0)
                            p[i][0]=1;
                    else{
                            if( (i-1>=0 && p[i-1][j]==1) ||  ( i-1>=0 && j-arr[i]>=0 && p[i-1 [j-arr[i]]==1) )
                                    p[i][j]=1;
                            else
                                    p[i][j]=0;
                            }
                    }
            }

    int min=INT_MAX;
    int half_sum=sum/2;
    for(i=half_sum;i>=0;i--)
            if(p[n][half_sum-i]==1 && min >(half_sum-i) ){
                    min = half_sum-i;
                    }
    return min;

}
```

But I am getting wrong output for array=[1,5]. 
I am solving using the idea given in problem 7 of
[Reference](http://people.csail.mit.edu/bdean/6.046/dp/)

Where I am doing wrong ?

Comment: what are you solving ? please describe the problem

Comment: Use a debugger to pin point the problem. I use `gdb` for this purpose.

Comment: you are mostly hitting a negative valued index

Comment: p[i-1][j-arr[i]] looks like being at fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error outcomes when you try to access `j-arr[i]` when it is negative.

In balanced partition algorithm, you assume that integers are nonnegative. So please update your code like this:

```
if(arr[i] <= j)
     p[i][j] = max( p[i-1][j] , p[i-1][j-arr[i]] );
else
     p[i][j] = p[i-1][j];
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late to answer the question but the problem that I can see in the code is due to the fact that the variable **i** ranges from **[0,n]** (n inclusive) :

**Code Snippet:**

```
if( (i-1>=0 && p[i-1][j]==1) ||  ( i-1>=0 && j-arr[i]>=0 && p[i-1 [j-arr[i]]==1) )
```

As size of the array is **n** i.e from **0** to **n-1** & **i** ranges from **[0,n]** so **a[n]** for **i = n** will throw an **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**, so you must use **j - arr[i-1]** in your code instead of **j - arr[i]**.

```
if( (i-1>=0 && p[i-1][j]==1) ||  ( i-1>=0 && j-arr[i-1]>=0 && p[i-1 [j-arr[i-1]]==1) )
```