# Can someone explain this source code for balanced partitioning?

Tags: c++

Can someone please explain this code in detail? I've tried debugging it but i can't figure out how it produces the result. I've been searching for a solution for the problem and this is the code that I stumbled upon, it produces accurate solutions and I would like to know how it works. Many thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
using namespace std;


int BalancedPartition ( int a[] , int n ){

int sum = 0;
for( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    sum += a[i];

int *s = new int[sum+1];

s[0] = 1;
for(int i = 1 ; i < sum+1 ; i++)    s[i] = 0;

int diff = INT_MAX , ans;

for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
{
    for(int j = sum ; j >= a[i] ; j--)
    {
        s[j] = s[j] | s[j-a[i]];
        if( s[j] == 1 )
        {
            if( diff > abs( sum/2 - j) )
            {
                diff = abs( sum/2 - j );
                ans = j;
            }

        }
    }
}
return sum-ans-ans;
}

int main()
{
    int n,result, arr[300];
    cin >>n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin>>arr[i];
}
result = BalancedPartition(arr,n);
cout <<abs(result); // The difference between the sums of the two subsets

return 0;
}
```

Comment: First it includes the `iostream` header...

Comment: The routine leaks memory.

Comment: I advise to start refactoring: eliminate the arrays and use `vector` instead. You'll get rid of the memory leak and the issue when the user enters a bigger number than `300`.

Comment: I know, i wrote the code in main, the input for my problem wont be larger than 300 numbers. And I know about the memory leak, I'm interested in the algorithm...

Comment: `The difference between the sums of the two subsets`, which two subsets?

Comment: Well the partition problem divides a set into two subsets, and the difference between the sums of these two subsets has to be minimal. Example: a set of numbers {1,5,9,3,8}, now the solution is two subsets, one subset with elements {9,3} and the other {8,5,1} the sum of the first one is 13 and the sum of the second is 13 so the difference between the sums is 0.

Comment: That should be explained in the question.

Comment: related to [14877639](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877639/balanced-partition-finding-the-minimized-sum-between-two-partitions-of-a-set-of)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `BalancedPartition` first computes the summation of the elements of the array `a` and stores it in `sum`. It then allocates an array `s` that is indexed by possible subset summation values. It serves as a bookkeeping structure that tracks the progress of the inner `for` loop. If `s[j]` is 1, it means the value `j` has been processed, where the value `j` represents the summation of some subset of elements in the array `a`. Initially, only `s[0]` is set to 1, which corresponds to the sum of no elements (the empty subset). `diff` is used to compute the subset with the summation closest to one half the value of `sum`, and this subset summation value is stored in `ans`. Once `ans` is correctly computed, the value returned is the difference between the summation of the elements not used in `ans` and `ans` itself, that is, `(sum - ans) - ans`. So, what's left is the double `for` loop, to see how it correctly arrives at `diff` and `ans`.

The outer `for` loop iterates `i` through all the indexes of the array `a`. The inner loop iterates `j` through all possible subset summation values, starting with `sum`. However, it only recognizes a subset summation value if the value is derivable from a previously recognized subset sum. That is, for any given iteration of `j`, `s[j]` becomes 1 only if `s[j - a[i]]` is 1. Since initially only the empty subset is recognized, the first iteration only recognizes `s[a[0]]`. The second iteration recognizes `s[a[1]]` and `s[a[0]+a[1]]`. The third iteration recognizes `s[a[2]]`, `s[a[0]+a[2]]`, `s[a[1]+a[2]]` and `s[a[0]+a[1]+a[2]]`. If you recognize the pattern, you can formulate an inductive argument for the correctness of the algorithm.